# Review Solution Actions: Retarget Projects - how to suppress it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The following dialog prompts me to upgrade the platform toolset and Windows SDK version of files generated for VS2017 when opening it in VS2019:

[image: Review Solution Actions]

How can I suppress this and have the action being taken to be **No Upgrade**?

After all I can still opt to do that later on via the context menu when right clicking a project in the Solution Explorer:

[image: Retarget Projects]

`devenv.com` from Visual Studio 2019 has:

```
/Upgrade                Upgrades the project or the solution and all projects in it.
                        A backup of these files will be created as appropriate. Please
                        see Help on 'Visual Studio Conversion Wizard' for more
                        information on the backup process.
```

... what I'd like is essentially the opposite, though. And I'd also like for that setting to persist.

Note: while the screenshots were taken with Visual Studio 2019, earlier Visual Studio versions (notably since 2012) show this behavior as these appear to be the ones to support multiple platform toolsets and Windows SDKs in parallel. Therefore I am also tagging [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio).

---

Searching the options I came up emptyhanded when looking for:

- action
- retarget
- target
- upgrade
- sdk
- platform
- toolset

Answer (score 6):

You can suppress this dialog per-project by editing the project file, `ProjectName.vcxproj`.

It is an XML file. You can edit it with any text editor. Inside the `<Project>` tag, add the following lines:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">     
  <VCProjectUpgraderObjectName>NoUpgrade</VCProjectUpgraderObjectName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-cpp-project-extensibility#disable-project-upgrade

Comment: This does not appear to work for Visual Studio 2019.  Clearing out the .suo file and re-opening the solution causes the dialog to appear even with this project setting.

Comment: This doesn't work in VS2022 either. Maybe this property only works on custom project upgraders, not the default project upgrader.

Comment: @UweBaemayr it works for me, however there was one difference not mentioned in the original answer: the `Label` attribute. I _think_ the attribute itself is less relevant than the _order_ in which this appears inside the `.vcxproj` file. For me this appears as the very first `PropertyGroup` right after the initial `<ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">`. Hope this helps and makes a difference.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thanks for the reminder -- I think you are correct, and should have updated this answer. The property group with the "globals" label occurs pretty early in the project and that's where I originally put this construct without success. I wound up adding the above construct, without any Label, as the very last <PropertyGroup> in the project file (right before the </Project> end tag and that worked. My theory, which is mine and belongs to me, is that this property must be set after Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props or maybe after $(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets is included.